# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined in my web page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

on web page http://www.club-emb.info/2018/

I see error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

I dont now why because i have load jquery and jquery file is first .

http://prntscr.com/i245kb

can you help me ?

thanks

Comment: You have a block of javascript within `id="contact-modal"`. This is _before_ you load the jQuery js file. The block needs to be moved to the bottom of your document, after jQuery is loaded.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You load your jQuery at the end of the code while you use some jQuery functions before (below your submit button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are calling jQuery function before actually importing it into your webpage, import jquery before you call the block :
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
}